# Product ID that has Two different category IDs in a catalog database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In a product catalog, would it be possible to have a single product that is a member of two different categories but just have a single product ID? Even if product_ID is the primary of the product table, and category_ID is the primary key of the category table?

For example, say the hierarchy goes like this:

```
Department (i.e. Sweaters)  
Category (i.e. Men's - cat 1, Women's - cat 2, children's - cat 3)
product_ID  (i.e. unisex sweater)
```

And you want the same sweater product to belong to both Men's sweaters and Women's sweaters.

So here's the part I can't quite figure out.
Would you have to store the sweater product TWICE in the Product table, each with a different product_ID, just so it could belong to two different categories? If so, then it seems as though a query such as:

```
SELECT 
  product_id, 
  prod_name, 
  prod_description 
from 
  PRODUCTS 
where 
  department_id = 1 
  and category_id IN (1, 2);
```

would display the sweater in the list returned (along with everything else in department 1 and categories 1 and 2), but it would be in the list TWICE - once for each of its two category IDs - correct? I know it has to be possible do this, but I just can't see how.

Can someone tell me how to have a single product belonging to two different categories in a product database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to store the product information more than once, so you need to have a separate table that is related to the products table and the categories table.  So if product #154 is in categories #4 and #5, your table will have:

```
Product     Category
154          4
154          5
```

Then when you pull all of the items in a category, you join the products table to this table to get all of the products in that category.

So if this new table is named ProductCategories, your query to pull products of a certain category (2, in this example) would look like this:

```
Select
  * 
from 
  Products as p
  INNER JOIN ProductCategories as con p.ProductId = c.productid
where 
  c.categoryid = 2
```

If you are building a production database, you need to study some relational database concepts before you go too much further.  If this is done wrong it will make life miserable for someone (either you or whoever succeeds you).

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense.  Thank you for the help!